# How to detect if windowsphone have the softkeys

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8.1, ionic-framework

I have build the app  with tabs at the bottom using ionic framework, it works perfect in iOS and Android device but the tabs are hidden in Windows Phone 8.1 because the device uses softkeys (back, start and search buttons).

Setting the app to Full screen does not work.

How can i detect if the device comes with the softkeys using javascript?

Comment: I would say there's something wrong with the code and wouldn't try to find ways to handle specific configurations with kludges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply identify it by comparing height of `<body>` and `screen`.

```
if(document.body.clientHeight < screen.height){ // assuming that your body doesn't have any top or bottom margin
 // soft key visible
}else{
 // soft key not visible
}
```

Comment: document.body.clientHeight is not working, thank for the clue.